# iOS: Back button label is cut off with custom font

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm using a custom font for the navigationItem; When I segue to another view controller the back button on the newly presented view controller is cut off on the left side. I have tried `setTitlePositionAdjustment(_ adjustment: UIOffset, for barMetrics: UIBarMetrics)` on the first view controller, before doing segue but it didn't displace the button:
[image]

And

[image]

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Show Contents" {
        if let viewController = segue.destination as? ContentsTableViewController {
                viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(10, 0), for: .default)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same issues if you use a Left to Right Language?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts yes

Comment: Can you share the font and text? Would make it easier to check.

Comment: @GuyKogus I uploaded them here https://github.com/maysamsh/Swift-Theming and if you want to set Farsi text, try this: خانه

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. I'm using `backBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font : UIFont(name: "B Koodak", size: 32)!], for: .normal)` and it looks ok to me, it's not cut off.

Comment: @GuyKogus would you please send the screenshot?

Comment: I had to add it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "خانه", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    backBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font : UIFont(name: "B Koodak", size: 32)!], for: .normal)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem
}
```

I get the following: [image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm running it on Xcode 9.3.1 in iPhone SE 11.3 simulator. It looks the same on the iPhone X simulator.

Comment: It was a weird problem, I changed the font size and it's fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when was using a custom font and I was hiding the navigation bar in the parent view and showing it in child views (in `viewWillAppear(_:)`).  Figuring that something in this action was causing the button label to get drawn too narrow, I tried calling various `UIKit` redrawing methods on the navigation bar (`setNeedsLayout()` & `setNeedsDisplay()`) in the child view controllers' `viewDidLoad()` methods, but to no avail.  I was able to get the label to draw properly by making the font size smaller, as the OP wrote.

I was eventually able to get it to draw properly at the correct size by manually setting the `backBarButtonItem` property to a new instance of `UIBarButtonItem` with `"Back"` as the title (in my parent view controller).  This is possibly why it worked in the accepted answer.  This seems to be a bug in `UIKit`, as I wouldn't think that hiding and showing the nav bar would cause this behavior.